# Android 10 Swipe Forward

Tags: navigation, android-10

I am using the new gesture navigation with Android 10 and was wondering if there is a way to have the swipe from the right side to the left trigger a "go forward" action. When I swipe from either the right to left or left to right, it always does a "go back" action. Is this a bug or does Android only support going back with these swipe gestures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a bug. Swiping to move forward as not yet been implemented natively only [swiping to move back](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/08/gesture-navigation-backstory.html?source=post_page-----812f62e4e83e----------------------&m=1)

> with the new system navigation mode - users can navigate back (left/right edge swipe), to the home screen (swipe up from the bottom), and trigger the device assistant (swipe in from the bottom corners) with gestures rather than buttons.

To use the swipe forward gesture, the app should implement it (ie Chrome).

[Gesture Navigation: A Backstory](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/08/gesture-navigation-backstory.html?source=post_page-----812f62e4e83e----------------------&m=1)